# Checking for null property

Tags: c#

I want to check that a property on an array which is itself a child object is not null.

So i  have

```
if (Parent.Child != null && Parent.Child[0] != null && Parent.Child[0].name != null)
var myName = Parent.Child[0].name
```

This seems like a very long winded way to get to the child[0].name whilst avoiding null reference exceptions. I am also getting index out of range errors. Is there a better way?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're getting `IndexOutOfRangeException` errors, that suggests that `Parent.Child` could be empty. So really you want:

```
if (Parent.Child != null && Parent.Child.Count > 0 && Parent.Child[0] != null &&
    Parent.Child[0].name != null)
{
    ...
}
```

There's nothing that would simplify this *very* much, although you could write a version of LINQ's `FirstOrDefault` method which even coped with the source being null:

```
public static T NullSafeFirstOrDefault(this IEnumerable<T> source)
{
    return source == null ? default(T) : source.FirstOrDefault();
}
```

Then:

```
var firstChild = Parent.Child.NullSafeFirstOrDefault();
if (firstChild != null && firstChild.name != null)
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: You also need to check if firstChild is null: `if ((firstChild != null) && (firstChild.name != null))`

Answer (score 1):

Your code appears OK apart from missing a test for the array being empty and is the correct defensive programming. You should extract this into a method to make it's intention clearer and your code here cleaner:

```
if (Parent.HasChild())
{
    var myName = Parent.Child[0].name;
}

public bool HasChild()
{
    return this.Child != null && this.Child.Count > 0 &&
           this.Child[0] != null && this.Child[0].name != null;
}
```

The only other way would be to wrap the code in a try/catch block:

```
try
{
    var myName = Parent.Child[0].name;
    ...
}
catch
{
}
```

However, this is bad programming practice as:

1. You are using exceptions to control program flow.
2. You are hiding other potentially serious errors.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
 var Names = new List<string>();

 if(Parent.Child != null && Parent.Child.Count() > 0){

 foreach(var item in Parent.Child) Names.Add(item.name)

 }
```

Comment: myName will only be available inside this block

Comment: so do it global. array or list or sth.
 I've edited.  see now.

Answer (score 0):

```
var ParentChild= Parent.Child[0] ;
if (Parent.Child != null && ParentChild != null &&ParentChild.name != null)
var myName = ParentChild.name
```

Comment: This will fail if `Child` is null or empty.

Answer (score -3):

Maybe simple try/catch will help?

```
var myName;
try
{
    myName = Parent.Child[0].name;
}
catch (NullReferenceException)  
{ myName = null; }
```

Comment: That's an *appalling* abuse of exceptions. Please don't do this.

Comment: @BlackBear OP wants to have myName either null or a value, so what's the problem?

Comment: The problem is that you are using exceptions as flow control. This is both inefficient and considered bad practice. Swallowing exceptions is a terrible practice.

Comment: @Oded I might suggest that the expression will be not null in most cases and only sometimes null, otherwise I expect more lines of code. So if it's exceptionally null, exception handling is just fine . Even it's a little bit slower than if/else, I would rather use it  instead of writing 15 additional lines of code **in this particular case** (not as common null checking practice)

Comment: @VladL: No, this is still *simply in inappropriate use of exceptions*. It gives the reader *no* idea about what you're trying to protect against, and gives the impression that you can't protect against these things by performing simple checks. (Quite why you think it's 15 lines of code is beyond me - your code is actually longer in terms of lines than just including all the checks as per my answer...)

Comment: @JonSkeet I really doubt that there are readers who don't understand the meaning of my code and at the same time understand your code. I'm not talking about the lines of code behind the exception handling, I'm talking about the usage of .net. I also mentioned that this kind of exception check is slower in my previous comment and don't really understand what you are trying to prove. I mentioned PROs, you mentioned contras and this code snippet will work in any case.

Comment: @JonSkeet btw. +1 to your answer

Comment: @VladL: The point is that readers would only understanding that *anything* could happen - not the specific things you're *expecting* to happen. For example, suppose the `Child` property throws an exception because it can't load a resource. That's not something the OP expected, and should probably still be thrown as an exception - but you're "handling" it by just catching everything. When you say "I'm not talking about the lines of code behind the exception handling" - you specified "I would rather use it instead of writing 15 additional lines of code in this particular case" [...]

Comment: (continued) when very clearly it *doesn't need* 15 lines of code in this particular case, as shown by my answer.